# STM32 External flash reading device ID using HAL libraries

Tags: c++

I am trying to interface with winbond external flash memory using QSPI interface : https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25m02gv%20revb%20070115.pdf. I am sending read Device ID command and I expect to see something like that: [Read device ID waveforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKFky.png)

I have connected Logic analyzer and I can see that I am sending the required command but I am not getting any answer on D1 line:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCQXd.png)

The code that I am trying to

```
void QSPI_read_ID(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi){
  QSPI_CommandTypeDef     sCommand;
    uint32_t    tmp;
    int         len;

  /* READ ID ------------------------------------------ */
  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.Instruction       = JEDEC_ID_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode       = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode          = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles       = 8;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode          = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;







  if (HAL_QSPI_Command(hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    QSPI_Flash_Error_Handler(hqspi); 
  }
```

If I change the dummy cycle number from 8 to lets say 24, I am able to read first 2 bytes of the device ID:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK3Pp.png)

I am not sure whether I am not understanding this properly. I was under the impression that if I send the read device ID command I should invoke the D1 line to send me the ID automatically. The problem that it wont let me use more than 32 dummy cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set recieved size as 3 and apply recieve function

```
void QSPI_read_ID(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi){
  QSPI_CommandTypeDef     sCommand;
    uint8_t tmp[3];
    int         len;

  /* READ ID ------------------------------------------ */
  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.Instruction       = JEDEC_ID_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode       = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode          = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
  sCommand.DummyCycles       = 8;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode          = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;
  sCommand.NbData        = 3;

  if (HAL_QSPI_Command(hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    QSPI_Flash_Error_Handler(hqspi); 
  }
  if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(hqspi, tmp , HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK){
    QSPI_Flash_Error_Handler(hqspi); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that works! I did not realise that I have to call the receive function to get the bytes ( Totally makes sense now ). Thanks.

Code here if anyone is struggling with the same problem:

```
void QSPI_read_ID(QSPI_HandleTypeDef *hqspi){
  QSPI_CommandTypeDef     sCommand;
 uint8_t reg[3]; // N25Q128A13EF840E 0xEF, 0xAB, 0x21

  /* READ ID ------------------------------------------ */
  sCommand.InstructionMode   = QSPI_INSTRUCTION_1_LINE;
  sCommand.Instruction       = JEDEC_ID_CMD;
  sCommand.AddressMode       = QSPI_ADDRESS_NONE;
  sCommand.AlternateByteMode = QSPI_ALTERNATE_BYTES_NONE;
  //sCommand.DataMode          = QSPI_DATA_NONE;
  sCommand.DataMode = QSPI_DATA_1_LINE;
  sCommand.NbData = sizeof(reg);
  sCommand.DummyCycles       = 8;
  sCommand.DdrMode           = QSPI_DDR_MODE_DISABLE;
  sCommand.DdrHoldHalfCycle  = QSPI_DDR_HHC_ANALOG_DELAY;
  sCommand.SIOOMode          = QSPI_SIOO_INST_EVERY_CMD;


  if (HAL_QSPI_Command(hqspi, &sCommand, HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    QSPI_Flash_Error_Handler(hqspi); 
  }

 memset(reg, 0, sizeof(reg));


    if (HAL_QSPI_Receive(hqspi, &reg[0], HAL_QPSI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
    {
        puts('ERROR:HAL_QSPI_Receive');
        Error_Handler();
    }


  HAL_Delay(10);


}
```